# How to reorder a SQL query?

Tags: t-sql, parameters, sql-server-2008

I am developing an sproc for SSMS 2008 R2 report parameter in SSRS.  I am currently populating this parameter with this script:

```
Select
    Null As [program_id],
    '-All-' As [program_name]
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
    [program_info_id] AS [program_id],
    [program_name]
FROM [evolv_reports].[dbo].[programs_view]
Order By [program_name]
```

But the problem is now there is a new program_name named "(MS) Family Preservation Services".  This Program is listed before "-All-", so that now this report parameter no longer defaults to "-All-".  How do I make "-All-" Listed first again?  Here is a portion of my current parameter output:

```
program_id  program_name
406B3C38-D8D3-4ED5-AC5B-9013D3662931    (MS) Family Preservation Services
NULL                                    -All-
F6E2C172-2BFB-45BC-B870-E7BC2414DD91    Adoptions - Agency
C766E084-AB03-41AD-92B9-494FF3975E10    Adoptions - Subcontract
C21DACE0-8F34-433D-BE24-A79DE322F7EF    AL Step down foster care
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT [program_id], [program_name] FROM 
(
   Select 
  Null As [program_id], 
  '-All-' As [program_name] ,
  0 as num1
  UNION ALL 
 SELECT DISTINCT 
  [program_info_id] AS [program_id], 
  [program_name] ,
  1 as num1
)a
ORDER BY a.num1, a.[program_name] -- or just by a.num1 if you don't need to sort by program_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
Select
    Null As [program_id],
    '-All-' As [program_name]
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
    [program_info_id] AS [program_id],
    [program_name]
FROM [evolv_reports].[dbo].[programs_view]
) AS T
Order By (CASE WHEN [program_id] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), [program_id]
```